# how to add value to each item of string array in string.xml in spinner

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, spinner

i have a problem here in using spinner, i want to add value to each array item in my string.xml

this is my code:

```
    <string-array name="hubungan">
            <item>Choice</item>
            <item>CHILD</item>
            <item>PARENT</item>
            <item>HUSBAND</item>
            <item>WIFE</item>
   </string-array>
```

I mean is:

```
<string-array name="hubungan">
                <item>Choice value="1"</item>
                <item>CHILD value="2"</item>
                <item>PARENT value="3"</item>
                <item>HUSBAND value="4"</item>
                <item>WIFE value="5"</item>
       </string-array>
```

Comment: You should store the values as a key value pairs for this.  Where the choice is key and 1 is its value. [`SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences) API is good for that.

Comment: what do you mean I don't understand about you give me an example?

Comment: Give more details. Is this all you want to achieve? will you read the saved values later? what have you tried with your spinner so far? do you want to show this array with its values in the spinner as well? Or you will always show the array without values? We need to know more details to help you with the best options.

Comment: what I mean is in the spinner, if you select child =1, parent=2.

Comment: each option has a different value, the value of the spinner option I want to take. not the spinner position

Comment: do the values change or values are constant?

Comment: If the values will not change, why don't you want to use spinner index instead of this?

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
 <Spinner
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/spinner"
     android:entries="@array/hubungan"
   />
```

Comment: <Spinner
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:entries="@array/hubungan">

Comment: I have made how to call value name?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you insist doing in this way try this example. The example will be as minimal as possible since you don't provide enough code.

Your string array values as you defined but I modified the way of storing by convenince.

```xml
<string-array name="hubungan">
    <item>Choice,1</item>
    <item>CHILD,2</item>
    <item>PARENT,3</item>
    <item>HUSBAND,4</item>
    <item>WIFE,5</item>
</string-array>
```

I will assume that you have a spinner and a textview in your activity / fragment. You can set this data and process it as needed like following:
Spinner definition in xml

```xml
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This code must be located in your `onCreate` method if you use an activity, or `onViewCreated` method if you use a fragment.

```java
// I assume that you've already instantiated the spinner and textview

// Setup for spinner
String[] hubungans = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.hubungan);
if(hubungans != null && hubungans.length > 0) {
    String[] names = new String[hubungans.length];
    String[] values = new String[hubungans.length];
    // Now we will parse the records and split them into name and value
    for(int i = 0; i < hubungans.length; i++) {
        String hubungan = hubungans[i];
        if(hubungan == null || hubungan.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: couldn't get record for index "+i);
            continue;
        }
        // Split the record by "," seperator for example for choice "Choice,1"
        String[] nameValue = hubungan.split(",");
        if(nameValue.length < 2) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: couldn't get split record for index "+i);
            continue;
        }
        names[i] = nameValue[0]; // first index will have the names
        values[i] = nameValue[1]; // second will have its value
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: names and values: "+ Arrays.toString(names)+" - "+Arrays.toString(values));
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, names);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            int val = 0;
            try {
                val = Integer.parseInt(values[position]); // Here you have value as numeric type
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                nfe.printStackTrace();
            }

            textView.setText(String.format("Value for %s is %d", names[position], val));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated: Hubungans cannot be read!");
}
```

There you go! Hope this helps you with your unique problem.